# Parse and filter json output in Ansible via json_query

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath, json-query

I have the below output that I'm trying to parse and filter:

```
  - name: lvs
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_lvm.lvs }}"
```

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "av_root_snapshot": {
            "size_g": "4.00",
            "vg": "vg_root"
        },
        "av_var_snapshot": {
            "size_g": "5.00",
            "vg": "vg_root"
        },
        "lv_root": {
            "size_g": "20.00",
            "vg": "vg_root"
        },
        "lv_var": {
            "size_g": "15.00",
            "vg": "vg_root"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a list of out it so it returns the following:

```
av_root_snapshot vg_root
av_var_snapshot vg_root
```

I am able to get the values of 'vg' via:

```
  - name: get snap
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_lvm.lvs | json_query('*.vg') }}"
```

But what I can't seem to figure out is how to filter the root object names that end in *snapshot and parse the value of "vg". I'm trying to do this so I can also delete those snapshots.

How do I properly filter the above output and parse for the information I need?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do. For example, how are you getting from `av_root_snapshot` to `av_root_snap1`?

Comment: sorry, typo. s/snap1/snapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"Delete object names that end 'snapshot' and parse the value of vg."***

A: Reject the keys matching the regex

```yaml
  lvs_no_snapshot: "{{ ansible_lvm.lvs|dict2items|
                       rejectattr('key', 'regex', '^.*_snapshot$')|
                       items2dict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  lvs_no_snapshot:
    lv_root:
      size_g: '20.00'
      vg: vg_root
    lv_var:
      size_g: '15.00'
      vg: vg_root
```

Then, you can get the list of the attributes *vg*

```yaml
  vg: "{{ lvs_no_snapshot|json_query('*.vg') }}"
```